# How to emulate any android version in linux?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, android-emulator, emulators

i was trying to emulate Android 5.0 (LRX21T) in linux, i downloaded the rom but i didn't find any good emulator, there is anyone that supports any version of android ? is that possible ?

Comment: What's wrong with the official emulator from Android SDK? Emulator images for Android 5 are still available in Android SDK/AVD manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you can try.

**Anbox:**

[Anbox](https://anbox.io/) is a wine-like android compatibility layer for Linux. It is not an emulator.It is based on android marshmallow I think.

**Geny Motion:**

[Geny Motion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is an android emulator with a cross-platform compatibility. You can install any android version you want.

**Android x86**

[It](https://www.android-x86.org/) is a project aims to port android to x86 processors. You can install it as a standalone OS. There are various distros available for this project such like RemixOS(discontinued),[Phoenix OS](http://www.phoenixos.com/en_US/phoenixos), Prime OS, [Bliss OS](https://blissos.org/) etc

**Android studio Android Emulator**

If your purpose is programming you better install the [emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) provided with android studio.